# Incorrect bracket using MnSymbol with fontspec

Tags: formatting, fontspec, mnsymbol

I am having issues with `MnSymbol` and `fontspec`, compiling math with large brackets is incorrect. I am currently compiling with xelatex.

I have searched around and found another post ([Link](https://ipfs-sec.stackexchange.cloudflare-ipfs.com/tex/A/question/399274.html)) but the only recommended solution was to stop using `MnSymbol`. I feel like I should be able to fix this?

Minimal Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Adobe Minion Pro}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\let\mathdollar\relax


\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    a = (b + c) = \big( a + b \big)
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    a 
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \left( \frac{a}{b} \right) = \bigg( \frac{a}{b} \bigg)
\end{equation*}   
\end{document}
```

[image: Typeset result]

Comment: I suggest using the "directional" `\big*` modifiers.  `\bigl]` and `\bigr[` give much better spacing especially for "inside out" delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand my error now.

Before, my font was not being applied to the body and MnSymbol was trying to work with computer modern.

Using `mathspec` instead of `fontspec` and using the command `\setallmainfonts{Adobe Minion Pro}` seems to set the parenthesis as expected

Minimal Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts{Adobe Minion Pro}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\let\mathdollar\relax


\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    a = (b + c) = \big( a + b \big)
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    a 
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \left( \frac{a}{b} \right) = \bigg( \frac{a}{b} \bigg)
\end{equation*}   
\end{document}
```

[image]